# How to select all rows from a Dask dataframe with value equal to minimal value of group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, dask

So I have following dask dataframe grouped by `Problem` column.

```
| Problem | Items   | Min_Dimension | Max_Dimension | Cost  |
|-------- |------   |---------------|-------------- |------ |
| A       | 7       | 2             | 15            | 23    |
| A       | 5       | 2             | 15            | 38    |
| A       | 15      | 2             | 15            | 23    |
| B       | 11      | 6             | 10            | 54    |
| B       | 10      | 6             | 10            | 48    |
| B       | 18      | 6             | 10            | 79    |
| C       | 50      | 8             | 25            | 120   |
| C       | 50      | 8             | 25            | 68    |
| C       | 48      | 8             | 25            | 68    |
| ...     | ...     | ...           | ...           | ...   |
```

The goal is to create a new dataframe with all rows where the `Cost` values is minimal for this particular `Problem` group. So we want following result:

```
| Problem | Items   | Min_Dimension | Max_Dimension | Cost  |
|-------- |------   |---------------|-------------- |------ |
| A       | 7       | 2             | 15            | 23    |
| A       | 15      | 2             | 15            | 23    |
| B       | 10      | 6             | 10            | 48    |
| C       | 50      | 8             | 25            | 68    |
| C       | 48      | 8             | 25            | 68    |
| ...     | ...     | ...           | ...           | ...   |
```

How can I achieve this result, i already tried using `idxmin()` as mentioned in another question on here, but then I get a `ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use set_index to set the index.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you create another dataframe that is grouped by `Problem` and `Cost.min()`? Let's say the new column is called `cost_min`.

```
df1 = df.groupby('Problem')['Cost'].min().reset_index()
```

Then, merge back this new `cost_min` column back to the dataframe.

```
df2 = pd.merge(df, df1, how='left', on='Problem')
```

From there, do something like:

`df_new = df2.loc[df2['Cost'] == df2['cost_min']]`

Just wrote some pseudocode, but I think that all works with `Dask`.